# QPalette does not work on sub QWidget

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qwidget, qpalette

I want to brush my sub widget with QLinerGradient. I have created ui by using QtDesigner.

[image]

But I can not brush this widget by using this code.(ui.colorBarWidget is normal QWidget was created by QtDesigner.)

```
   QPalette palette;
   QLinearGradient gradient(ui.colorBarWidget->rect().topLeft(),ui.colorBarWidget->rect().topRight());

   gradient.setColorAt(0,   Qt::blue);
   gradient.setColorAt(0.2, Qt::green);
   gradient.setColorAt(0.4, Qt::red);
   gradient.setColorAt(0.6, Qt::yellow);
   gradient.setColorAt(1,   Qt::cyan);
   palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, gradient);

   ui.colorBarWidget->setPalette(palette);
```

In addition this code works in stand alone QWidget application.This is its output:

[image]

But I can not do same thing in my design. I can do this with styleSheet

```
ui.colorBarWidget->setStyleSheet( "background-color: qlineargradient( x1:0 y1:0, x2:0 y2:1, stop:0 blue, stop:1 red )" ); /* works */
```

but why  I can not do this with QPalette.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. If you use after setting palette:

```
ui.colorBarWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
```

This property is default false. So you should enable it then everything is fine. But also you should consider the size, fixed size better for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of widget is `ui.colorBarWidget`, but it looks it's not an entry widget, like `QLineEdit` or `QComboBox`.

So, you should use a `QPalette::Window` role instead of `QPalette::Base`.

In the Qt documentation, there is a following description for the `QPalette::Base role`:

> Used mostly as the background color for text entry widgets, but can
>   also be used for other painting - such as the background of combobox
>   drop down lists and toolbar handles. It is usually white or another
>   light color.

Comment: I tried Base, Background,Window...but still can not do. Also ui.colorBarWidget is normal QWidget was created from QtDesigner.